# exclamatory sentence: HOW vs. WHAT?

Tags: differences

I say:

> A) What a good heart you have!
>
> B) How beautiful a girl she is!
>
> C) What awful weather!
>
> D) How I wish to have a long vacation these days!
>
> E) How little money we have!

Do these following sentences make sense ?

> A1) How good a heart you have!
>
> B1) What a beautiful girl she is!
>
> C1) How awful weather!
>
> D1) What I wish to have a long vacation these days!
>
> E1) What little money we have!
>
> F1) What nice music it is!
>
> F2) How nice music it is!
>
> G1) What beautiful girls they are!
>
> G2) How beautiful girls they are!

Thanks.

Comment: You may find [ell.se] more suitable for basic questions on English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B, E, F, and G1 are all perfectly correct usages. The others I'm afraid are not. From my own experience with French I think interrogative pronouns are very difficult to master. It is really only a matter of practice and experience.  The following would be alright:

What awful weather!  How I wish I could have a long vacation!

I'm sorry. I meant B1, E1, F1, And G1. A,B,C and E are also correct.

Comment: A, C & E are also fine. I question whether B & D are idiomatic English. B1, C1, F1 & G1 are also OK.

Comment: I think B, D, E1 and are fine but C1 isn't. So C1, D1, F2, and G2 are the ungrammatical ones. I can fix them all, but I really can't figure out the rule, which is what a good answer really should have.

Comment: Here are some fixes (they're not unique). C1: "How awful the weather is." D1: "What I wish to have is a long vacation." F2: "How nice the music is." G2: "How beautiful those girls are!"

Comment: APOLOGIES TO THE OP. I hadn't realised that A to E were part of the question. see my amended answer above.

Comment: Thanks WS2, TrevorD and Peter Shor.
I especially appreciate these fixes from Peter Shor.

Answer (score 1):

In British English, the exclamatory "how" must be immediately followed by the relative adjective or adverb :

"How tall he is, and how fast he runs !"

I would then prefer :

C) "What an awful weather !"  or  "How awful a weather !"

D) "How much I wish ... !"

C1) "How awful a weather !"

D1) "What is my wish ... !"  or  "How much I wish ... !"

and F2) to F1), and G2) to G1)

Comment: The original D is fine. And your answers here for C and C1 sound terrible to me, a native speaker of American English, because *weather* is not a count noun, so you can't say "a weather" or "an awful weather". The original C was fine.

Comment: @PeterShor: Shouldn't it at least be "*What* awful weather" rather than "*How* awful weather?"

Comment: @Armen: I agree with you. The original C was "*What* awful weather!". The original C1, "*How* awful weather", is ungrammatical. If you want to use *how*, you could say "*How* awful the weather is!"

Comment: Thanks Mark Thorin. I speak AmE, "a weather" sounds a little weird to me.